# Solving Euler 4 with CLP

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I've got this very slow solution to Project Euler 4,

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

euler_004(P) :-
  A in 1..9,
  B in 0..9,
  C in 0..9,
  P #= A * 100001 + B * 10010 + C * 1100,
  D in 100..999,
  E in 100..999,
  E #>= D,
  P #= D * E,
  labeling([max(P)], [P]).
```

Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Your questions are about [tag:clpfd] only. So the tag [tag:clp] is not appropriate. And BTW, if you delete your questions as you already did, you should be aware that it is not very attractive to answer them in due time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original model takes 32.8s on my machine using SWI-Prolog. This version, using `ff,bisect` as search strategies, takes 3.1s:

```
euler4c(P) :-
  A in 1..9,
  B in 0..9,
  C in 0..9,
  D in 100..999,
  E in 100..999,
  E #>= D,
  P #= D * E,
  P #= A * 100001 + B * 10010 + C * 1100,  
  labeling([max(P),ff,bisect], [P]). % 3.1s
```

Also, SWI Prolog's CLP solver is generally not the fastest CLP solver, so other Prolog's might be faster.

Also, see my non-CLP SWI Prolog approaches to this problem: http://hakank.org/swi_prolog/euler4.pl (solving the problem in about 0.2s).

Comment: unfortunately the link doesn't work for me.

Comment: What error do you get? Here's another link to the program: https://github.com/hakank/hakank/blob/master/swi_prolog/euler4.pl

Comment: "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource"

Comment: @vasily Hmm, please try again with http://hakank.org/swi_prolog/euler4.pl .

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative search strategy that cuts down the time tremendously.

```
...
labeling([max(P),down], [A,B,C]).
```

The rationale is that:

1. Searching on `A`, `B`, and `C` instead of `P` potentially reduces the size of the search space from the order of `10^6` to only `10^3`.
2. In order to maximize `P`, it is interesting to try larger values of `A`, `B`, and `C` first (especially `A`), which is achieved by using the search option `down`.

In SWISH, this reduced the time from ~63 seconds to around 0.2 second.